# How to make connector compatible with new Date / Date and Time types

Tags: looker-studio

We have a community connector which makes us of [Data Studio Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/advanced-services) to run a query on a specific BigQuery dataset.

Since the [new **Date** type](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6401549) was introduced on 15th September 2020, any reports including a date or date and time type will fail.

From the logs, the query that is being executed includes a section like:

> PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', SAFE_CAST(t0.updated AS STRING)) AS t0_qt_bthq67ilcc

where "updated" is the name of the field of the type DATE.

When this query is executed BigQuery is reporting `Failed to parse input string "2020-09-23"`.

Any data sources that were created before 15th September are using the compatibility mode, which are continuing to work fine.

The community connector includes `setUseStandardSql(true)` so I don't believe it is using Legacy SQL.

**What can we do to add compatibility for this new date type?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for identifying this bug. We are looking into this and should have a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to make the connector compatible.

To resolve this I had to edit the SQL query to `FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", fieldName) AS fieldName`.

If the field is a timestamp it's `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", fieldName) AS fieldName`. Just posting in case anyone else comes across this issue.